# Accessing e.Row in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get the value stored in `Text` attribute of the `lbljob_id`.However i can't access e.Row in code behind

Here is my code

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_ApplyRowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
         <Columns>

                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job Title" DataField="Job_Title" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job Description" DataField="Job_Desc" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recruiter FName" DataField="User_FName" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recruiter LName" DataField="User_LName" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Deadline" DataField="End_Date" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recruiter Email" DataField="Company_Email" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Apply">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbljob_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_ID") %>' />
                                    <asp:Button ID="apply" runat="server" CommandName="Apply" Text="Apply"   />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT Job_ID,Job_Title,Job_Desc,User_FName,User_LName,Company_Email,Start_Date,End_Date,Status  
FROM [JobDetails].[Job] AS J
INNER JOIN [UserDetails].[Recruiter] As R 
ON J.Recruiter_ID = R.Recruiter_ID
INNER JOIN [UserDetails].[User] As U
ON R.User_ID = U.User_ID"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JPortalCS %>" />
```

Code behind

```
Protected Sub GridView1_ApplyRowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
   Dim Job_ID As Integer = e.Row.FindControl("Job_ID").Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Paste Complete gridview mark up, and the error, is debugger hits your event?

Comment: @Imad I added full gridview

Comment: @Imad error says that e.Row is not accessible in this context because it is friend so i assume it must be event

Comment: your Label ID is `lbljob_id` but your Finding Control As `Job_ID`?  It Should be  `Dim lbljobId As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lbljob_id"), Label)` then you can cast it to integer.

Comment: go to grid view properties and and see if there is Modifiers property and revert back to me

Answer (score 0):

You could have got easily by searching in [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=asp.net%20gridview%20commandeventargs&oq=GridView%20commandeve&ie=UTF-8&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0l5.25012j0j7&sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.106379543,d.dGo&biw=1366&bih=653&dpr=1&ech=1&psi=ZQAzVsefCsLP0gSDwpj4Dw.1446183014278.3&ei=ZQAzVsefCsLP0gSDwpj4Dw&emsg=NCSR&noj=1), the first result is pointing to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) example.

What I was using is, I was adding an `OnClick` event to the `Button` and get the row by calling `NamingContainer` property of that `Button`.

```
<asp:Button ID="apply" runat="server" Text="Apply"  OnClick="btnApply_Click" />
```

And in code behind

```
Protected Sub btnApply_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, Button).NamingContainer,GridViewRow)
End Sub
```

Since you need to get the integer which is stored in the label, you need to get the label control first. To access any control inside GridViewRow, first find it and then cast it.

For your label,

```
Dim lbljob_id as Label = CType(row.FindControl("lbljob_id"),Label)
```

Next you need number which is stored in the label text. Since text is a String datatype, you need to parse it to the datatype integer.

```
Dim Job_ID As Integer = int.Parse(lbljob_id.Text.Trim())
```